# Change LogIn route

Tags: laravel

I am working in Laravel auth application and when my user is log out I want to redirect it to custom static page and from there I want to redirect to login page again by clicking button on that page.
For example when user is trying to access some particular route, and he is unauthorized then I want to redirect with satatic.blade.php and from there I want to redirect it to log in page, How can I make it happen?

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't mention which Laravel version you are using and which scaffolding you are using, I am assuming you are using Laravel 5.5/6 with LaravelUI/default auth scaffolding.

You should have `App\\Http\\Controllers\\Auth` namespace where you kept all auth related controller.

You should have one `LoginController.php` which contains all default login behavior inside `AuthenticatesUsers` trait. We should override the login method inside our controller.

Copy this code to your `LoginController` class to do so.

```
public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validateLogin($request);

        if (method_exists($this, 'hasTooManyLoginAttempts') &&
            $this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
            $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

            return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
        }

        // Here is our custom logic check occurs before login
        if ($this->userIsnotAuthorized()) { // All your logic checks are inside 'userIsnotAuthorized()' method. Use any function or static check here
            return redirect()->to('/static/page'); // Also can use route name / url
        }

        if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {
            return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
        }

        $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);

        return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
    }
```

EDIT #1

If you want to have the same check for all protected routes, you should generate a middleware with `php artisan make:middleware CheckResourceAccessMiddleware` and use the same in your route.

In `CheckResourceAccessMiddleware`'s `handle` method

```
    // Here is our custom logic check occurs before login
    if ($this->userIsnotAuthorized()) { // All your logic checks are inside 'userIsnotAuthorized()' method. Use any function or static check here
        return redirect()->to('/static/page'); // redirect to static page which indicates unauthorized user note
    }

    return $next($request); // proceed to your page as user is authorized
```

to register the middleware edit your `app/Http/Kernel.php` and add this line to `$routeMiddleware` array

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ...
    'resource_access' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckResourceAccessMiddleware::class,
];
```

After this step., you can use the middleware in any routes you want to protect

```
Route::get('/protected', [Controller::class, 'method'])->middleware('resource_access');
```

OR

```
// Middleware will be applied to all routes inside it
Route::middleware('resource_access')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/protected', [Controller::class, 'method']);
    // all other protected routes will be here
});
```

Comment: I am using laravel 8

Comment: Method App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::userIsnotAuthorized does not exist.
I am getting this error

Comment: That method is just for demonstration purpose. you should implement that method to write your user authorization logic

Comment: Thanks For the help, I really appreciate!

Comment: What i am trying to do is if user is not log in and try to access some secured route from URL then it should be redirected to that custom/static page

Comment: @Milanjotva in this case you should not only check the logic in login only. You should add the middleware to all the protected routes. THis middleware will get executed before the controller method.

Comment: How can I do the same with Laravel auth middlewear??

Comment: You should check with all features of laravel from documentation @ https://laravel.com/docs/8.x

Answer (score 0):

I found different approaches for this problem, Later I Found the best solution, as mention below,

In App\Middlewear\Authenticate.php, I have to change from return route('login');
to return route('my_custom_page_route');
From my custom page I can redirect it to auth login page easily.

Thank you everyone who suggest the best solutions.